# Opening WMV files in Virtual Dub

Tags: virtualdub

Is there an easy way to open WMV files in Virtual Dub ? I came across [this tutorial](http://www.ehow.com/how_5011067_open-wmv-files-virtualdub.html) but the plugin used in it if unavailable (page offline).

Answer (score 1):

There is a mirror for the plugin used below:

http://gral.y0.pl/~fcchandler/

And an alternative plugin based on ffmpeg :

http://code.google.com/p/ffinputdriver/downloads/list